# Tagging best practices in Azure DeVops for docker images deployed on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-aks

Does anyone have experience in building and pushing docker images + deploying them to AKS via Azure DevOps?

When I build and push an image I can use the variable `$(Build.Repository.Name):$(Build.BuildId).`

But then I have my `.yaml` files that I have in my release pipeline to deploy the images.  I cannot (or don't know how) to refer to that variable `$(Build.Repository.Name):$(Build.BuildId)`.

Does anyone have experience in automating this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How I got it working for me is by using "tokerisation of the yaml file".

During the build fase (build and push of the image to the private repo I use a default variable in Azure Devops, $(Build.BuidId), as tag for the docker image.

Build image task
[image: Build image]

Push image task

[image: Push image]

In the the deployment yaml for the image I refer to:

[image: Deployment yaml]

Then for the deployment before I apply the yaml files, with kubectl apply task, I use the task "Replace tokens". You can specify which files to replace tokens in. Since I only used a token for the image I only selected the deployment yaml file.

[image: artifact source name]
[image: replace token task]

What it does it replaces #{Release.Artifacts.acpyaml.BuildId}# with the actual build nr of the last build, so when it starts pulling the image it has the right tag.

See a full example described on [Tokenised version of yaml](https://medium.com/@marcodesanctis2/a-build-and-release-pipeline-in-vsts-for-docker-and-azure-kubernetes-service-aks-41efc9a0c5c4)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21159453)

Comment: Ah ok, sorry.. you are right. Didn't think about that.

Comment: I adjusted the answer with a hopefully better description for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

If you have on the release pipeline only 1 artifact so you can use the variables also in the release in the same way (`$(Build.Repository.Name):$(Build.BuildId)`).

If you more then 1 artifact the variables will refer to your primary artifacts:

[image]

If you want to use the variables to other artifacts (not the primary) you can use this way:

```
Release.Artifacts.{alias}.BuildId
```

The `{alias}` is the alias name of the artifacts:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Shayki, I use the kubectl apply plugin. I cannot pass on a variable unfortunately. And in the deployment yaml file I cannot refer to the variable (I think?!).

Comment: Going to try this https://medium.com/@marcodesanctis2/a-build-and-release-pipeline-in-vsts-for-docker-and-azure-kubernetes-service-aks-41efc9a0c5c4

Comment: Do you mean in the Kubernetes YAML file?

Comment: Yes. In the yaml file you can, apparently, do refer to a "variable/token" and in the release pipeline use a task to replace these tokens.

Comment: Ohh ok, and you don't want to do it in this way (replace tokens)?

Comment: No, I thought I couldn't refer to a variable (or token) in a yaml file until I found that medium article :). So going to try that replace token solution right now :).
The other solution would be to use a shell script in combination with sed to replace variables with variables set in the release pipeline

Comment: Great :) so in the replace tokens task you can put the variable like in the build.

Comment: See https://medium.com/@marcodesanctis2/a-build-and-release-pipeline-in-vsts-for-docker-and-azure-kubernetes-service-aks-41efc9a0c5c4 for how it works. It works like a charm for me